# How can we pass a ${BASEWORK} directory from Bitbake recipe to CMAKE for using find library function from CMAKE?

Tags: cmake, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, build-system

I want to pass a variable `BASEWORKDIR`  yocto recipe variable to CMake so that it can search for library in a particular folder using `find_library()` function  for .so library. But it is not working. I printed it also I.e for debugging the Cmake file `message(${BASEWORKDIR})` but this variable is empty. This variable is defined in Bitbake.conf file in my yocto system.

Comment: If `BASEWORKDIR` is some kind of environment variable, you can use CMake's `env` command: [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/ENV.html).

Comment: BASEWORKDIR is env  variable of yocto.So can it be accessed by env variable of cmake??

Comment: Bitbake should already be invoking cmake with parameters to set the sysroots and search paths properly.  Are you sure that your recipes are written per Yocto's documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this to use the Yocto environment variables in CMake:

```
if(DEFINED ENV{BASEWORKDIR})
    set(YOCTO_BASEWORK_DIR $ENV{BASEWORKDIR} CACHE INTERNAL "Path retrieved from environment variable.")
endif()
```

This creates a new CMake variable called `YOCTO_BASEWORK_DIR` using the system environment variable `BASEWORKDIR`.